# Dynamic text input of equation for graphing

Tags: dynamic, scoping, inputfield

I'd like a simple interface where the user can input (by text) a function $f(x)$, and then the function, its even part, and its odd part are all plotted on the same axes.  I'd also like PlotLegend to show the mathematical form of $f(x)$, as well as the even and the odd functions.

Recall that $f_e = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2}$ and $f_o = \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2}$.  So for instance if the user puts in `Sin[x] + 3 Cos[x] + x^2`, I'd like the following three graphs plotted:

- Sin[x] + 3 Cos[x] + x^2
- 3 Cos[x] + x^2
- Sin[x]

I'd also like the PlotLegends to be

- $f(x) = \sin x + 3 \cos x + x^2$
- $f_e (x) = 3 \cos x + x^2$
- $f_o (x) = \sin x$

Here is a weak start:

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{f = Sin[x] + 2 Cos[x] + x^2},
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]],
    Dynamic[Plot[{f, f/2, f/3}, {x, -5, 5},
      ImageSize -> 300,
      PlotLegends -> {"f = " f, 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(e\)]\) = " f/2, 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(o\)]\) = " f/4}]]}]]]
```

Note that this does not compute the even and the odd parts.

I cannot get the plot legends to be properly typeset either.  For instance there are spurious and unnecessary parentheses around entire expression; the equations are sometimes mangled by being "factored," and so on.

Finally, I want each time the user types a new equation into the InputField, the previous graph disappears.  That is, I don't want the user to use this code 10 times with different equations and get a set of 10 graphs remaining;  only the most recent graph should remain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
evenPart = Simplify@(# + (# /. #2 -> -#2))/2 &;

oddPart = Simplify@(# - (# /. #2 -> -#2))/2 &;

Panel[DynamicModule[{f = Sin[x] + 2 Cos[x] + x^2}, 
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], 
    Dynamic[Plot[Evaluate@{f, evenPart[f, x], oddPart[f, x]}, 
      {x, -5, 5}, 
      ImageSize -> 300, 
      PlotLegends -> {Row[{Style["f ", Italic], " = ", f}], 
        Row[{Subscript[Style["f ", Italic], e], " = ", evenPart[f, x]}], 
        Row[{Subscript[Style["f ", Italic], o], " = ", oddPart[f, x]}]}]]}]]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent... almost... ($+1$)   The last request stated was that multiple uses of the code do not lead to a long string of plots.  Only the last plot should be visible at any time.  Does this mean the code should be a Manipulate?

Comment: David, if you use Return after entering your input in the input field (instead of Shift+Return) the changes in plot will be _in-place_, so the code will not produce a string of plots.

Comment: Oh gee... how did I not know *that*?  Thanks as always.  ($\checkmark$)